# Map nested beans list : "org.mapstruct.Mapping"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I want to map the `Abc` class to `AbcDTO` using "org.mapstruct.Mapping"

```
class Abc {
    private List<Xyz> xyz = null;
    private String uvw;
    private String cde;
}

class AbcDTO{
    private List<XyzDTO> xyz = null;
    private String uvw;
    private String cde;
}

class Xyz{
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String docId;
}

class  XyzDTO{
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private DocDTO document;
}
```

I tried to map the classes by using the annotation:

```
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "xyz.docId", target = "xyz.doc")
    })
 abcDTO abcToabcDTO(abc abc)
```

Can someone please help with how do i iterate through the nested beans and map the `docId` to `doc?`
If the names are same they map automatically but I want to map from `docId` to `doc`.

Answer (score 1):

when you want map list you can define it :

```
@Mapping(source="docId", target="doc")
XyzDTO xyzToXyzDTO(XyZ xyz);

@Mapping(source="xyz", target="xyz") //useless if two lists got same name, but good for comprehention
AbcDTO abcToAbcDTA(Abc abc);
```

Comment: I want to map abc to abcDto without creating another abstract class xyzToXyzDTO

Comment: You cannot use @Mapper ? 
Like:
 `code`@Mapper
public abstract class AbcDTOMapper {

@Mapping(source="docId", target="doc")
XyzDTO xyzToXyzDTO(XyZ xyz);

@Mapping(source="xyz", target="xyz") //useless if two lists got same name, but good for comprehention
AbcDTO abcToAbcDTO(Abc abc);
} `code`

And use your only mapper.abcToAbcDTO(...) ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as below (
you can give it a try):

````
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target="doc", source="abc.docId")
  })
AbcDTO abcToabcDTO(Abc abc);```
````

Comment: its giving an error showing :
Error:(25, 37) java: No property named "abc.docId exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "abc.empty"?

Comment: Is there a docId field in Abc?